# Compose navigation - passing arguments to startDestination of nested graph

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation-graph, jetpack-compose-navigation

What is the correct way of passing arguments to startDestination of a nested navigation graph? See this example:

```
private const val featureGraphRoute = "feature_graph"

private const val firstRouteArg = "intArgument"
private const val firstRoute = "first_route/{$firstRouteArg}"
private const val secondRoute = "second_route"

fun NavController.navigateToFeatureGraph(argument:Int, navOptions: NavOptions? = null) {
    //TODO: pass the argument
    this.navigate(featureGraphRoute, navOptions)
}

fun NavGraphBuilder.featureGraph() {
    navigation(
        route = featureGraphRoute,
        startDestination = firstRoute
    ) {
        composable(
            route = firstRoute,
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(firstRouteArg){
                    type = NavType.IntType
                }
            )
        ) { backStackEntry ->
            FirstRoute(
                argument = backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt(firstRouteArg)
            )
        }
        composable(route = firstRoute) {
            SecondRoute()
        }
    }
}
```

Adding the same argument to the `featureGraphRoute` does seem to work but only if using `NavType.StringType`. Otherwise app crashes with exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong argument type for 'intArgument' in argument bundle. integer expected.

**EDIT:**

I somehow missed the fact that `NavGraphBuilder.navigation` has an overload that takes `arguments`. Moving the `navArgument` declaration up one level does prevent the crash.